# htaccess - read string at end of URL, append to script, redirect

Tags: .htaccess

My URL is https://example.com/555

I want to use htaccess to redirect this to https://example.com/view.php?id=555

I know I need to use the RewriteRule as follows

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/view.php?id= [R=301,L]
```

How do I read and append the number in the URL to the script with htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `R` flag as it will redirect to your internal URL. Also to capture numbers just `\d+` in regex:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ /view.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Tried it - it does redirect. However, the URL doesn't change but opens the page. In my page/PHP script, I can't read the ID using $id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: My bad, I missed out `$1` from target. Try again my updated rule.